# не могу подружить Tomcat и nginx

Tags: nginx, tomcat, proxy

Всем доброго времени суток.
Имею желание спрятать приложение на томкат за nginx по следующей схеме: [Http Client] <- https -> [Nginx] <- http -> [Tomcat] Tomcat 8.0.53 и Nginx 1.16.1 на Windows Server 12. Nginx 80 порт http -> Томкат 8080 порт в режиме http -> Томкат 443 порт https - ок. Как только я в nginx включаю прослушку 443 и пытаюсь перенаправить трафик с него на 8080 или 8443 Томката - облом: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR или ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS в зависимости от того что я наконфижу. Сертификаты сгенерены letsencrypt
Конфиги, которые я пытаюсь заставить работать:

```
<Service name="Catalina">
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" address="127.0.0.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    Server="Apache"
    SSLEnabled="false" secure="false"
    proxyName="localhost" proxyPort="443"
/>

<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           maxThreads="200" enableLookups="false" acceptCount="200"
           scheme="https" secure="true"
           SSLEnabled="false" sslProtocol="TLS" proxyPort="443" 
           SSLCertificateFile="${catalina.base}/conf/platform.crt"
           SSLCertificateKeyFile="${catalina.base}/conf/platform.key"
           SSLCACertificateFile="${catalina.base}/conf/ca.crt"
           Server="Apache"
/>

<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>localhost</Alias>

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="site_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
  </Host>
</Engine>
```

Nginx:

```
          server {  

    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name my.foo.bar;
    listen [::]:443;

    ssl_certificate C:/NewDev/nginx-1.16.1/conf/platform.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key C:/NewDev/nginx-1.16.1/conf/platform.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;



# default dest for backend at Tomcat
        location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering     off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
  }
```

Единственное что вижу ошибки в логах nginx:

```
2019/12/23 17:18:35 [error] 5752#5116: *1 connect() failed (10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it) while connecting to upstream, client: 109.73.8.14, server: my.foo.bar, request: "GET /main?sysname=logon HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://[::1]:8080/main?sysname=logon", host: "my.foo.bar"

2019/12/23 17:18:57 [warn] 5752#5116: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 109.73.8.14, server: my.foo.bar, request: "GET /main?sysname=logon HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://[::1]:8080/main?sysname=logon", host: "my.foo.bar"
```

Comment: Я вообще не специалист в настройке каталины, но мне кажется проблема в том, что Вы пытаетесь зачем-то двойное шифрование сделать. Обычно когда люди прячут что-то за nginx, они SSL подключают _только_ на nginx и далее то приложение, которое будет выступать бэкэндом должно работать _только_ по http без каких-либо редиректов от слова _совсем_ , по сему настоятельно рекомендую пересмотреть настройки каталины.

Comment: `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme` зачем? у вас же там обычный http

Comment: @nobody коннектор https в конфиге каталины остался чисто для галочки - если его закомментировать, то томкат не запускается. Мысль как раз была в том, что бы ssl соединения nginx принимал и прокидывал на томкат по http уже

Comment: @AndreyMihalev возможно. это мой первый опыт в конфиге nginx и я далеко не на 100% понял как он там с заголовками работает, используя свои переменные